# Count how much area of one layer feature are within another feature polygon

Tags: arcgis-pro, modelbuilder, intersection, tabulate, calculate-geometry

I am trying to count what percentage or area covers features from one layer my default layer - (usually polygon). And write these result into separate fields inside atribute table of my default layer (with the feature name). I am also trying to do this process a bit more automatic. I was able to achieve this by tabulate intersection, splitting by attribute and then joining the output back. I ve also tried to do a model from it, but it is not very responsible and also quite slow. Do you have some other ideas how to achieve this?

[image] - example

[image] - my model

Comment: The Iterator (and everything beyond it) should be moved into its own sub-model.  Then you can include the sub-model within the main model.  As it is, your entire model gets run for each iteration of the iterator.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Not sure how to do it.?

Comment: If I do a Google search for "arcgis model sub-model"  To top result provides all the information you need:  https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/help/analysis/geoprocessing/modelbuilder/add-a-submodel-to-a-model.htm .  If this doesn't help, then you may need to ask another question that explains the problem fully.

Comment: @SonofaBeach is correct the iterator and join field need to be in a sub model. A quirk of an iterator is that EVERYTHING in your model is run as many times as your iterator loops, that's explained in the help file. So anything upstream or not even joined to the iterator will run X times. But this quirk happens for the model, so a model inside a model is a sub-model and the iterator only affects whats in the sub-model.